# display element in block

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display element like this image [image] But when I wrap in `<ion-item>` it display like this image [image] .What should I do to change it.. I've using `display:block` but it not working.

page

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
     <h2>Name</h2>
      <div>
        <ion-input placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: `display: flex; flex-direction: column` on the parent.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Position attribute:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating">Floating Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still display flex

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using? and share your both html Ans CSS.

Comment: i'm using ionic 6.10.0

Comment: use: `position="stacked"` and don't use  <h2> and <div>. just use Ionic input same as my example. check Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input